pgfplotstable: compute averages of columns
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/mean/.style args={#1#2#3}{
        create col/expr={(\thisrowno{#1} + \thisrowno{#2} + \thisrowno{#3})/3}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
1  1    2    3
2  2    3    4
3  3    4    5
4  4    5    6
}\mydata

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]     
\addplot[] table [x index=0, y=mean{1}{2}{3}] {\mydata};     
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

This code gives the error Sorry, could not retrieve column 'mean{1}{2}{3}' from ...
What I want is to compute the average of three columns (with given indices) of a table.
How can I do it?
